# Something is wrong with installing ROS on my IntelGalileo board?

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to operate the ROS on my IntelGalilo board and followed the tutoria IntelGalile/HydroGalileoInitialInstall. However, it had something wrong when I handled the step of "bitbake image-full".

Pseudo is not present but is required, building this first before the main build
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

```
Please install the following missing utilities: makeinfo
```

ERROR: Execution of event handler 'check_sanity_eventhandler' failed

How can I solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151066/something-is-wrong-with-installing-ros-on-my-intelgalileo-board?/) by [dhu_student](https://answers.ros.org/users/14606/dhu_student/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the command:
sudo apt-get install makeinfo

I think this should fix your problem :)

---

Originally posted by [FocaaBR](https://answers.ros.org/users/15156/focaabr/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0